# Is there an Ubuntu distribution which is customized to run on the android kernel?

Tags: kernel, android

Every android device has a more or less customized kernel. Most of these are open source?!(I am not sure about the "most".) Is there a Linux or even better ubuntu distro which comes with has support for lots of android devices out of the box?
Thanks?
And which is nearly as easily installable as "Ubuntu  for Desktop"?

Comment: You are aware that Android is itself Linux-based?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Ubuntu for Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_for_Android).

Also, it is made clear at Ubuntu.com that [Ubuntu is available for phones](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone).

Answer (score 0):

You can explore Ubuntu for android devices and Google also for various sites.

[Ubuntu for Devices](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/devices/)

[Ubuntu Wiki for Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_for_Android)

As of now these android devices are supported i.e. Nexus4,Nexus 7 2013 WiFi,Nexus 10.

Comment: Hi I modified my question, I've added this: And which is nearly as easily installable as "Ubuntu for Desktop"?